# Click event not triggered after focusout event

Tags: jquery

After the Focusout event, the click event is not triggered.

My design is,

```
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Submit" />
```

jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var field = $("#txt");
var btn = $("#btnClick");
field.on("focusin", f1);
field.on("focusout", f2);
btn.on("click", f3);

function f1() {
    field.removeClass("c1").addClass("c2");
}

function f2() {
    field.removeClass("c2").addClass("c1");
}

function f3() {
    alert('hi');
}
});
```

Style,

```
.c1 { height:40px; }
.c2 { height:250px;}
```

And I have also attached Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kramesh/YQxXN/).

Comment: In the javascript variable declarations seems unnecessary, please try this updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YQxXN/8/

Comment: @Pratik, Thanks for the consideration. I have used some external functions inside the functions block (f1,f2,f3) and field and btn values are dynamic in my real time code.

Comment: such cases are appropriate then, but my reference was the code posted.Hope you have solved your problem by any way. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thats because it doesn't have enough time to get the click to trigger since the button moves position. You can see the click works if you hold the mousedown and move the mouse to the button and let the click go and you'll see click works.

Either use `btn.on('mousedown',f3);` or position the button so it doesn't get moved on focusout

[**DEMO mousedown**](http://jsfiddle.net/YQxXN/1/)

[**DEMO button positioned**](http://jsfiddle.net/YQxXN/9/)

The way click works is that you have mousedown on an element and mouseup on it aswell, thats when it triggers click

Comment: you rock! perfect solution :D

Answer (score 1):

After the Focusout event first focus out from textarea then it will take click action of 
button

**in js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var field = $("#txt");
    var btn = $("#btnClick");
    field.on("focusin", f1);
    field.on("focusout", f2);
    btn.on("click", f3);//use btn.on("mousedown", f3); here to prevent the focusout before click

    function f1() {
        field.removeClass("c1").addClass("c2");
    }

    function f2() {
        field.removeClass("c2").addClass("c1");
        alert("focusout");
    }

    function f3() {
        alert('hi');
    }

});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/YQxXN/10/)**

Comment: That doesn't alert "hi"

Comment: It doesn't work since it doesn't alert "hi" when you click from textarea to the button @Riturajratan The only difference from this and OPs code is that it just alerts "focusout" on focusout

Comment: i already explain it why this happen  any way thanks for focus on this answer i will check again

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to give a timeout of the focusout event. For example:

```
object.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
    /* Set some timeout */
    setTimeout(function () {
    // Things to do before the focus is out
    }, 50)
});
```