# Click event not triggered after element focusout

Tags: jquery

Click event not triggered after focusout event, in textarea. `Tabs and button` click is not worked. Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MMg5u/2/).

*Steps to produce:*

focusin to the textarea and click any tabs or buttons in the popup.

Comment: could you please explain which click event is not working and scenario that you are tring?

Comment: You asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18848738/474535) It even has an accepted answer. What's the difference ?

Comment: Yes @bart s, but its not worked in this scenario.

Comment: Do you want to trigger the click event on Ok button of the dialog when focusout from the textarea right?

Answer (score 1):

Not the nicest solution but you can delay the toggling of the classes like this

```
function f2() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    field.removeClass("c2").addClass("c1");
  },200);
}
```

[see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMg5u/3/)

The reason that it happens is exactly the same as in your question from a few hours before. The only difference is that you have jQuery UI tabs now instead of a button